# Reference element, element varible, innerHtml in js

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reference, pass-by-reference

I have a element in html such as:

```
<div id='div1'><button onclick="function...." id='btn1'/></div>
```

then,I get this element save to a variable, such as var a=document.getElementById('div1');
b=a.innerHtml;
then, I change innerHtml of #div1, such as: a.innerHtml('AAABBB'); It is:

```
<div id='div1'>AAABBB</div>
```

then, I set content of #div1 to origin, such as: a.innerHtml = b;
but when I click in button, function not run. I think element is a reference variable, then, the function has been changed. So, I don't know how to fix this.
[in consolelog, how different of result, they are text, nodeList, tag???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVgNB.png)

Comment: `a.innerHtml()` : innerHTML is not a function, if that is your actual code you should be getting an error about it in the console

Comment: oh, It is my mistake, i will edit, but I want to know about my problem

Comment: What is your actual onclick code?

Comment: my onClick is generated by a componet of React

Comment: const action = (cell, row) => {
        return (
        <div className='action'>
            <div className='remove' onClick={() => this.onRemove(row)}><i className="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></div>
            <button className='btn btnNormal btnDarkBlue radius-2' 
              style={{ float:'right', width:'70px' }} 
              onClick={()=>{  window.open(`${VIEW_FILE_URL_API+row.file_name}`, '_blank');  }}>
              VIEW
            </button>
        </div>)
    }

Comment: it just open a new link

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow!  Please take a moment to read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Please post the code you have tried (preferably a minimal piece that demonstrates the problem - any error messages you receive, any output you get and what you want to happen.  We are all here to help, but you are far more likely to get it if you present your needs more clearly.